# logrotate compress files after the postrotate script

Tags: linux, shell, logging, compression, logrotate

I have an application generating a really heavy big log file every days (~800MB a day), thus I need to compress them but since the compression takes time, I want that logrotate compress the file after reloading/sending HUP signal to the application.

```
/var/log/myapp.log {
    rotate 7
    size 500M
    compress
    weekly
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/myapp.pid 2>/dev/null` 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

Is it already the case that the compression takes place after the postrotate (which would be counter-intuitive)?
If not Can anyone tell me if it's possible to do that without an extra command script (an option or some trick)?

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `postrotate` script does run before compression occurs: from the man page for [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html)

> The next section of the config files defined how to handle the log file
>          /var/log/messages. The log will go through five weekly rotations before
>          being  removed. After the log file has been rotated (but before the old
>          version of the log has been compressed), the command /sbin/killall -HUP
>          syslogd will be executed.

In any case, you can use the `delaycompress` option to defer compression to the next rotation.

Comment: Thanks, I should have read more carefully the man page ... Though this information should also be under the compress option explanation.

Comment: Note to all readers, the above comment seems false based on answer below by @jw-padded-to-three-chars, please refer also to the latter.

Comment: @Thomas: Comment was based on this quote from the man page `The sharedscripts means that the postrotate script will only be run once (after the old logs have been compressed), not  once  for each log which is rotated.` It appears to be my misunderstanding of that quote. `postrotate` scripts are always run before compression of the current logs. (the `delaycompress` option is not affected by `sharedscripts` in any way, other than occuring before the `prerotate` scripts are run)

Comment: I do believe that the man page is the one responsible for the confusion with those examples. It mentions old logs being compressed, when there is no `delaycompress` directive in the section. The reader is left to infer that `sharedscripts` is the directive that influences order of execution between `compress` and `postrotate`.

Comment: People interested in the order things are done by logrotate will find `logrotate -d` useful - it tells you exactly what's happening. You'll probably want to use `-f` as well.

Comment: So what does the manual means then? To me the "after the old logs have been compressed" part seems not just confusing, but wrong.

Comment: Note: if in postrotate section you need move file(s) to any external storage (ftp, smb, s3, etc) - you have to use ```lastaction/endscript``` section

Answer (score 53):

Adding this info here in case of anyone else that comes across this thread when actually searching for wanting a way to run a script on a file once compression has completed.

As suggested above using **postrotate/endscript** is no good for that.

Instead you can use **lastaction/endscript**, which does the job perfectly.

Comment: You're the man. Saved me at least 30 minutes of googling/reading.

Comment: You may want to create a separate question and answer it, you'll gain reputation and improve the quality of this answer thread.

Answer (score 27):

The *postrotate* script **always** runs **before** compression even when *sharedscripts* is in effect. Hasturkun's additional response to the first answer is therefore incorrect. When *sharedscripts* is in effect the only compression performed before the *postrotate* is for old uncompressed logs left lying around because of a *delaycompress*. For the current logs, compression is **always** performed **after** running the *postrotate* script.

Comment: I just discovered this for myself. Agreed that @Hasturkun should revise or remove his comment.

Comment: Had this been a comment, I would have likely responded in less than eight months

Answer (score 2):

@Hasturkun - One cannot add a comment unless their reputation is first above 50.

To make sure of what logrotate will do, either

1. test your configuration with, -d: debug which tests but does not do
   anything, and -f: force it to run
2. or you can execute logrotate with
   the -v verbose flag

With a configuration that uses a sharedscript for postrotate

```
$ logrotate -d -f <logrotate.conf file>
```

Shows the following steps:

```
rotating pattern: /tmp/log/messages /tmp/log/maillog /tmp/log/cron
...
renaming /tmp/log/messages to /tmp/log/messages.1
renaming /tmp/log/maillog to /tmp/log/maillog.1
renaming /tmp/log/cron to /tmp/log/cron.1
running postrotate script
<kill-hup-script executed here>
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
```

Comment: Assuming you are referring to my (retracted) comment, IIRC (It's been a while since then) I checked the logrotate source when the error was brought up. It was indeed wrong, the behavior is unaffected. In any case, testing your configuration is probably a good idea.